# Does not appear all the cards in the deck

Tags: anki

I export a deck (without schedule) with 45 cards and then I delete it from Anki.

However, if I import it again there are only 20 new cards. I can find all the 45 in the browser though.
The funny thing is if I import on my MacBook (older version of anki) appear all the 45 cards as new, when I open the same apkg file on my PC (latest version of anki) there is only 20 cards. And unfortunately, my students have the same problem.
What can cause this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked in the settings if there's a limit of 20 new cards per day?